# Optional Foreign Key in TBH EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I want to use an optinal foreign key in TBH (Table per Hierarchy) in EF Core. I tried many solutions but none of them worked. I want to set the foreign key to null on delete of the other entity. In my code that would mean that I want to set `FriendRequest` in `FriendRequestNotification` to null when a `FriendRequest` is deleted.

I am always receiving this error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: 23503: update or delete on table "FriendRequests" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Notifications_FriendRequests_FriendRequestId" on table "Notifications"

**DbContext**

```
 public class HankContext : DbContext
 {
    public virtual DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Notification>()
            .HasDiscriminator<NotificationType>("Type")
            .HasValue<FriendRequestNotification>(NotificationType.FriendRequest)
            .HasValue<FriendAcceptNotification>(NotificationType.AcceptedFriend);

        //this part is the one which I thought would solve the problem
        builder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
               .HasOne<FriendRequestNotification>()
               .WithOne(x => x.FriendRequest)
               .IsRequired(false)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
      }
    }
```

**FriendRequestNotification**

```
public class FriendRequestNotification : Notification
{
    public Guid? FriendRequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual FriendRequest FriendRequest { get; set; }
}
```

**Notification**

```
public abstract class Notification
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public NotificationType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User Receiver { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve that the foreign key described above is set to null? Thank you for your help.